# Getting Preview URL for images in confirmation emails in Web 8

Tags: web8, outbound-email

We recently upgrade from 2013 sp1 to web 8 .We are facing issue while receiving confirmation email from tridion all images URL inside email is appearing with Preview

> /Preview/en/assets/images/email-images/header-10-10128-2.jpg

the email page is already published.

in the old version of mailing where we were able to select publicationtarget but in the WEB8 this option has been removed so what is alternate way to define publicationtarget in web8?

Comment: Are you using the AM or OE TBBs in your templates? Did you update them as part of the upgrade (using the "Create Default Building Blocks" option in Template Builder)?

Comment: it`s better solution try using event system.

Comment: Yes Peter we updated all outbound related TBBs but still having same issue.for some mailing image urls are correct and some mailing image urls are coming with preview.

Comment: @Sudhakar how we can use event system

Comment: The old mailings which accepts publicationtarget are working fine but the new mailings are having this issue since WEB8 removed publicationtarget.